# jQuery Ajax Cross Domain Issue: Response data with HTML tags, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to get data via Ajax not at all success for Cross Domain. Tried almost all possibilities like `dataFilter, crossDomain, dataType` for the below mentioned Ajax setting up,

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://103.20.126.126/autosuggest.php?cases=what&search=mum&city=Mumbai&area=Santacruz+West&scity=Mumbai&callback=?',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataFilter: function(data){
            var data = JSON.stringify(data); return data;
        },
        error: function(error){
        alert('error');
        },
        success: function(data){
        alert('success');
        }
    });
```

All we left to know is adding header to php file but, as we don't have access to the particular server file its impossible to add `header` to respective php.

Also tried php `file_get_content()`, this works but running this for auto-complete suggestions getting delay in every response.

If anyone come up with a valid solutions to get success data from this url will be appreciable. Java-script concepts otherthan ajax if works also acceptable. Thanks

For your reference: [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2LjvL/3/)

Comment: put `jsonp` as datatype in cross domain request

Comment: tried even that.. instead of jsonp added callback=?

Comment: The server script has to implement JSONP, you can't just assume it does.

Comment: We have no access to the server script.. response will change as per the search input, this is how it was designed.. response is a valid json as we could see in browser network preview..